# How to work with a Json object with more than one position in flutter (REST API)

Tags: flutter

Given the documentation of Flutter with examples, I am coding an application that consumes a REST server, but in the documentation example there is only one item in the Json object, already in the application I have been doing for several ... I am in doubt how to display each Item separated and all (for)

I've tried, print the element on the console, but no results since then ...
And when I build a Widget with it on the screen the application is only "loading"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    Widget buttonSection = Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.fiber_new),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Notícias',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Eventos',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Calendário Acadêmico',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),
                ],
              ),


        //  _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.fiber_new, 'Notícias'),
         // _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.business, 'Eventos'),
         // _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.calendar_today, 'Calendário Acadêmico'),
        ],
      ),
    );
   Widget buttonSection2 = Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Cardárpio',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Mapa do Campus',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  tooltip: 'fiber_new',
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                ),
                  Text('Horário do Ónibus',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0)),                  
                  ),

                ],
              ),


        //  _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.fiber_new, 'Notícias'),
         // _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.business, 'Eventos'),
         // _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.calendar_today, 'Calendário Acadêmico'),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open new route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
            ),
          buttonSection,
          buttonSection2,
          ],
          ),

    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Noticia> post;
  SecondRoute({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FutureBuilder<NoticiaListModel>(
                    future: fetchPost(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text("${snapshot.data.noticiaList.first.title}",softWrap: true,)
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}",softWrap: true,);
                      }
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<NoticiaListModel> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://app.bambui.ifmg.edu.br/integracao/noticia/retornarNoticias');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return NoticiaListModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Falha ao carregar um post');
  }
}
class NoticiaListModel {

  final List<Noticia> noticiaList;

  NoticiaListModel({this.noticiaList});

  factory NoticiaListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<Noticia> results = [];
    for(int i = 0; i<json.length; i++){
      Noticia _noticia = Noticia(id: json[i]['id'], title: json[i]['titulo']);
      results.add(_noticia);
    }
    return NoticiaListModel(noticiaList: results);
  }
}


class Noticia {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  Noticia({this.id, this.title});
}
```

What I hope is that on the second screen composed by the SecondRoute class the back button (test button) is displayed, and the items coming from the Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix. You need to listen to `fetchPost()` in your `FutureBuilder`. I have added a new class `NoticiaListModel` which will hold the list of `JSON` objects. I have removed the `Button` for clear printing of the output:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Noticia> post;
  SecondRoute({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FutureBuilder<NoticiaListModel>(
                    future: fetchPost(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text("${snapshot.data.noticiaList.first.title}",softWrap: true,)
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}",softWrap: true,);
                      }
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<NoticiaListModel> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://app.bambui.ifmg.edu.br/integracao/noticia/retornarNoticias');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return NoticiaListModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Falha ao carregar um post');
  }
}

class NoticiaListModel {

  final List<Noticia> noticiaList;

  NoticiaListModel({this.noticiaList});

  factory NoticiaListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<Noticia> results = [];
    for(int i = 0; i<json.length; i++){
      Noticia _noticia = Noticia(id: json[i]['id'], title: json[i]['titulo']);
      results.add(_noticia);
    }
    return NoticiaListModel(noticiaList: results);
  }
}

class Noticia {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  Noticia({this.id, this.title});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. See my complete code, my goal is to click the button ("Open new route") and go to a second screen with the data obtained through Json ...
When I changed the file as you recommended. An exception was caused so that I can no longer change the screen and can not identify what caused this exception

Comment: I managed to clear the exception, it was the version I was using from the flutter. my new step now is to have a 5-position listview with 5 titles come from Json ... Thanks for the help